# How to link a Bitmap to a button in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner programmer and I was wondering how I would go about linking an image to a button. Its for a childrens maths game which contains various questions like "how many sheep are there?", which would require them to select a button which has a certain value. Sorry if this is a really simple thing but I'm having some issues with it.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Or do you expect us to show it to you? Start by **googling**.

Comment: What are the issues?  What is the platform — WinForms?  WPF?  Web?  Show the code that isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean by link? To put an image on a button can be easily done in designer.

Comment: [How To Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: What does the image have to do with sheep?  What does "link" mean?  Do you want to show the image on the button?  Or does the image contain the question?

Comment: You can use the Button's Tag property to store anything, including a PictureBox or an image name..

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are doing a Windows Forms Application, you first place a button wherever you want, you can size it, put text on it... For what you want, those are the steps:

1. Select the button and find the Properties tab attached in the IDE.
2. In appearance, find the property "Text" and leave it blank, if there was any text.
3. In appearance section too, find BackgroundImage and click the button with "..." in the space.
4. When a window called "Select resource" appears, select "Local resource" and click "Import". When selected, click OK.
5. Now the image is binded to your Button background. Resize it as you want.

I hope this helps. There's not much info in the question.